# Libgdx swipe gesture across actor

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, game-physics

How can I detect a swipe gesture across an actor, started outside the actor's boundary

The action would be as follows
1. User touched the screen outside of the actor boundary
2. The user's finger moves across the screen and enters the actor boundary
3. The actor is then dragged by the user's finger
4. The actor is released once the user lifts their finger

I am able to drag an actor using the dragListener and drag method on the actor. This only works for me if the user touches down inside the actors boundary and then moves their finger to drag the actor.

I would like the user to be able to touch down outside the actor's boundary and then enter and drag the actor

Thanks for your help, I will continue to investigate and post if I find the anwser

Comment: Are you using Box2D or any other physics lib to define bodies?

Comment: No, I am using gdx.scenes.scene2d.
I have a Screen in it I placed a Stage and in that I have placed an Actor

I can detect the drag on the Stage and I can detect the drag on an Actor. But I cant pass the drag on the stage to the Actor. The Actor ignores the drag if the drag started outside the actor

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the actor when swiped? Sticking to the finger when finger enters actor? Only going to the swipe direction with constant speed or immediately by a fixed amount of distance?

Comment: What I can do:
If you touch within the actors boundary and drag, the actor sticks to the finger and moves with it. 

What I would like:
If you touch outside the actor and swipe into the actor's boundary, I would also like the actor to move/stick with the figure. But the Actor ignores the gesture since it was started outside of its boundary.

Thanks for your relpies

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a function which does the following in order:

- STEP1: Go to STEP2 if Gdx.input.justTouched() method returns true,
  otherwise repeat
- STEP2: Go to STEP3 if yourActor.hit(Gdx.input.getX(),
  Gdx.input.getY(), true) return true, otherwise repeat
- STEP3: Subject Gdx.input.getDeltaX() and Gdx.input.getDeltaY() to
  yourActor and go to STEP4
- STEP4: Go to STEP3 if Gdx.input.isTouched() is true, otherwise go to 
  STEP1

The main logic is something similar to this, you should be able to get the idea and find yourself a way to implement it in somewhere in your main game loop. Also, if you are not familiar with the functions available in the Input and Actor classes, you should have a look at the API.